# How to password protect a directory on vercel?

Tags: next.js, vercel

I have a fully static website (html and css) hosted on Vercel and would like to password protect:
A) the entire site;
B) or a specific directory within the website.

It doesn't have to be top level security, just to hide it from the public and web crawlers.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/authentication

Answer (score 4):

If you have a custom domain for this site (anything other than the default `*.vercel.app`), [Octauthent](https://octauthent.com/) can help you password protect either the whole website or specific directories.

Octauthent is a no-code solution, and it's free (with premium features).

[Here is a detailed tutorial](https://octauthent.medium.com/password-protect-your-vercel-site-with-octauthent-1f79e37b1d91) for websites hosted on Vercel

Answer (score 1):

You can password protect the entire site by visiting your Project Settings, selecting Security, and then enabling [Password Protection](https://vercel.com/docs/platform/projects#password-protection). Then check the box that says "Also protect my Production Deployment".

If you need to password protect a specific path or directory (instead of the entire website), you'll need to implement it yourself using a [Serverless Function](https://vercel.com/docs/serverless-functions/introduction) or [getServerSideProps()](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering) so that you can read the request headers and dynamically respond with a password form or the protected content.

Comment: hi there what exactly is viewable if i DON'T have a password protection on my vercel site ? I have no idea, the folder structure ? the env variables ? the git repo, what is the actual real benefit of having a password protected website other than coworkers mingling in the code ? Thanks

Comment: Without password protection, then anyone can view your website. Your "folder structure" could be viewed depending on what you mean. Your "env variables" can never be viewed by anyone outside of your Team. Your "git repo" is not hosted by Vercel and therefore cannot be managed by Vercel. However, I think it's best to create a new question instead of using the comments on this existing question.